# Have Independent Inner Content in React Native Component

Tags: react-native

I have created an React Native component and added some Animations to it. Now when I surround some other Element (Ex: Text) with that element, the Text gets the Animation too. How to avoid this? I want to have my component to have the animation but the inner components of it to stay still.

MyImage Component Code:

```
return (
    <Image
        defaultSource={{uri: './placeholder.jpg'}}
        source={this.props.sourceUri}
        style={imageStyle}>
        <View>{this.props.children}</View>
    </Image>
);
```

Implementation:

```
<MyImage imageWidth={Dimensions.get('window').width} imageHeight={Dimensions.get('window').height / 100 * 30} sourceUri={{uri: item.image}}>
    <View style={styles.nameContainer}>
        <Text style={styles.textMain}>{item.name}</Text>
    </View>
</MyImage>
```

How to achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of making the children of your custom component children of the image, they have to be on the same level, positioned absolute. MyImage would VERY roughly look like this:

```
<View style={{ ... apply width and height ..., position: 'relative' }}>
    <Image style={{ top:0, bottom:0, left:0 right: 0, position: 'absolute' }} />
    <View  style={{ top:0, bottom:0, left:0 right: 0, position: 'absolute' }}>this.props.children}</View>
</View>
```